# Windows resized to top half screen after removing HDMI

Tags: hdmi, monitors

After removing the HDMI cable for my 2nd monitor (in elementary 7 Horus), every window is resized to the top half screen, even when maximizing them.

Only by logging out this bug ends.

**Display info**

I use a Samsung 44" TV as a monitor, but it's detected as 85" (had the same issue in elementary 5)

[image: built-in display]
[image: second monitor]

This is how it looks

[image]
[image]

**Hardware**

```
~$ lscpu
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  4
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6006U CPU @ 2.00GHz
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               78
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  2
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            3
    CPU max MHz:         2000.0000
    CPU min MHz:         400.0000
    BogoMIPS:            3999.93
```

Comment: Welcome to eOS:SE. This is quite odd. Could you [edit] your question to include the hardware specifications of your machine? With this, it may be possible to determine the cause and — ideally — a solution 

Comment: After a bunch of digging, this seems to be a math problem that occurs when one display is not “flush” with another on the X axis. As a result, when one display is removed, the system miscalculates its window bounds. This is found with a couple of Desktop Environments. As of yet, I’ve not found a solution, as I don’t see a way to force a DE to rediscover its bounds 

Comment: Thanks for the response. Seems to happen when dock is not hidden. This problem does not occur when changing Dock settings to "Hide when: any window overlaps the dock".

Comment: In that case, it sounds like a bug [that should be reported](https://github.com/elementary/os/issues). There may be others who are facing the same problem 